# Set custom time in dhtmlx scheduler on dropdown change event

Tags: javascript, scheduler, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx scheduler.I want to set a custom time on select box change event in light box.for eg.I am having services in dropdown and specific time is assignd for every services.So on change of this dropdown I want to assign a time.

Also i want to hide a time section.If i am hideing time section it is showing uncaught error of time and date.

Please help me out of this.
Below is the url for my code

http://pastebin.com/mjuHRCR3

I have attached a screen shot for the same
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXapk.png

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of a select control can have **onchange** property, you can assign onchange handler for the selectbox there

```
{..., type:"select", onchange:function(e) {} },
```

Lightbox values can be set using **scheduler.formSection** method
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_formsection.html

> Also i want to hide a time section. If i am hideing time section it is
>   showing uncaught error of time and date.

If your datepicker control sets correct date values to an event, absence of time-period control shouldn't cause any errors.
You can set use **map_to:"auto"** option, and assign all values inside the **get_values** method of the datepicker control. Similar how it's done in this example
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_lightbox_editor.html#example